# Mongoid join two of three columns in pluck()

Tags: mongoid

In a controller, I need to create a nested array that returns:

[["first_name - last_name", "id"]]

From the persons table which contains the three columns: first_name, last_name, id.

I have the query below that joins all three with a ' - ', but I only need to join the first two columns. How would I achieve this?

```
Person.pluck("first_name", "last_name", "id").map{|e| e.join(' - ')}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @coreyward works if you want to go the SQL literal route. You could also change the `map` block to the following, which isn't terribly elegant but works.

```
map{|e| [e[0..1].join(' - '), e[2]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer was written when the answer was tagged [rails] and no mention was made of Mongo.*

Generally I recommend avoiding SQL literals in ActiveRecord queries, but this gets the job done:

```
 Person.pluck("concat(first_name, ' - ', last_name)", :id)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in rails? I'm using mongoid and am trying to avoid using literals

Comment: @HoosierCoder This is written for Rails, but you should let your database handle data manipulation. It will always be more performant, and [MongoDB supports concatenation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) as well. You should use it.